# Convert from a csv only a column to a dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

There are already questions in this direction, but in my situation I have the following problem:

The column alias contains dictionaries. If I use the csv reader I get strings.

I have solved this problem with ast eval, but it is very slow and consumes a lot of resources.

The alternative json.loads does not work because of encoding.

Some Ideas to solve this?

CSV File:

```
id;name;partei;term;wikidata;alias
2a24b32c-8f68-4a5c-bfb4-392262e15a78;Adolf Freiherr Spies von Büllesheim;CDU;10;Q361600;{}
9aaa1167-a566-4911-ac60-ab987b6dbd6a;Adolf Herkenrath;CDU;10;Q362100;{}
c371060d-ced3-4dc6-bf0e-48acd83f8d1d;Adolf Müller;CDU;10;Q363453;{'nl': ['Adolf Muller']}
41cf84b8-a02e-42f1-a70a-c0a613e6c8ad;Adolf Müller-Emmert;SPD;10;Q363451;{'de': ['Müller-Emmert'], 'nl': ['Adolf Muller-Emmert']}
15a7fe06-8007-4ff0-9250-dc7917711b54;Adolf Roth;CDU;10;Q363697;{}
```

Code:

```
with open(PATH_CSV+'mdb_file_2123.csv', "r", encoding="utf8") as csv8:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv8, delimiter=';')
    for row in csv_reader:

        if not (ast.literal_eval(row['alias'])):
            pass

        elif (ast.literal_eval(row['alias'])):
            known_as_list = list()

            for values in ast.literal_eval(row['alias']).values():
                for aliases in values:
                    known_as_list.append(aliases)
```

Its working good, but very slowly.

Comment: Just a drop in the ocean, but you can call the `ast.literal_eval()` only once, removing the `pass` code. So something like: `if (ast.literal_eval(row['alias'])): ....`.

Comment: Similar to what @toti08 says, you can compute the `ast.literal_eval()` once, store it in a variable, and then refer to that variable. This'll save time and resources as you don't need to repeatedly compute the `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: its working with speed O(n*m**2) where n=row m = length of dict, thats why its a bit slow, try removing last for, and just type known_as_list.append(aliases), cuz dict values() gives same as for aliases in values: in my code

Comment: How big is your file? Is using multiple processes an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ast` library consumes lots of memory (refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25527687/5397845)) and I would suggest avoid using that while converting a simple string of dictionary format into python dictionary. Instead we can try python's builtin `eval` function to overcome latency due to imported modules. As some discussions suggest `eval` is extremely dangerous while dealing with strings which are sensitive. Example: `eval('os.system("rm -rf /")')`. But if we are very sure that that the csv content will not carry such sensitive commands we can make use of `eval` without worrying.

```
with open('input.csv', encoding='utf-8') as fd:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(fd, delimiter=';')

    for row in csv_reader:
        # Convert dictionary in string format to python format
        row['alias'] = eval(row['alias'])

        # Filter empty dictionaries
        if not bool(row['alias']):
            continue

        known_as_list = [aliases for values in row['alias'].values() for aliases in values]

        print(known_as_list)
```

Output

```
C:\Python34\python.exe c:\so\51712444\eval_demo.py
['Adolf Muller']
['Müller-Emmert', 'Adolf Muller-Emmert']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid calling `literal_eval` three times (one is sufficient) —
while I was at it I've cleaned up, or so I think, your code using a SO
classic (3013 upvotes!) contribution

```
from ast import literal_eval

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/2749397 by Alex Martelli
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
...

for row in csv_reader:
    known_as_list = flatten(literal_eval(row['alias']).values())
```

From the excerpt of data shown from the OP, it seems to be possible to
avoid calling `literal_eval` on a significant part of the rows

```
...
for row in csv_reader:
    if row['alias'] != '{}':
        known_as_list = flatten(literal_eval(row['alias']).values())
```